# with_context issue in oddo v13

Tags: python, odoo-12

I have a function ***func1***, it has DICTIONARY in a context

```
def func1(self, num):
    num = self.env.get('career.lib').with_context({'start':True}).func2(num)
    return num
```

within **func1** there is a call of **func2** where it has another Dictionary within a context.

```
def func2(self, num):
    if num.get('x', False):
        c = {'x': 123}
        a,b = self.env.get('x.help').with_context({'end':False,'middle':False}).func3(c)
        return c
```

with in **func2** I have another function **func3**, where i used **self._context** to get all the context dictionary from **func1** and **func2** in it.

```
def func3(self, some_x):
    -------------
    --------------
    --------------
    --------------
    context = dict(self._context)
    ---------------
    ---------------
    
    return something
```

But the context gives me  --   **{'end':False,'middle':False}**

But i need  -- **{'start':True,'end':False,'middle':False}**

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Krish

You're replacing context every time you need to carry forwards the data with context.
You can pass/update and get the context in this way,

```
def func2(self, num):
    # Copy the Context
    ctx = self._context.copy()
    if num.get('x', False):
        c = {'x': 123}
        # Update the Context
        ctx.update({'end': False, 'middle': False})
        a, b = self.env.get('x.help').with_context(ctx).func3(c)
        return c
```

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the "original" context when calling `with_context` with a dictionary.

You could use kwargs instead or named parameters:

```py
self.env.get('x.help').with_context(end=False, middle=False)
```

or

```py
my_context_update = {'end': False, 'middle': False}
self.env.get('x.help').with_context(**my_context_update)
```